# conversion error from string, when using params in SQL

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird

using Delphi 2010 (Firebird [testing], MS Sql Server, Oracle [production])

The following is my SQL

```
SELECT p.script_no, MIN(p.start_Time) as startTime, MAX(p.end_Time) as endTime, 
SUM(p.duration) as TotalDuration
FROM phase_times p
WHERE (p.script_no=:scriptNo) AND (Trunc(p.start_time) >= :beginDateRange) AND (Trunc(p.start_time) <= :endDateRange) 
GROUP BY p.script_no



ParamByName('beginDateRange').AsDate:= Date - 30;
ParamByName('endDateRange').AsDate:= Date;
```

I am getting a "conversion error from string - 10-25-2012" and i am not sure why, since my datetime fields are in the "10/25/2012 9:20:49 AM" format in the database.

If i change it to the following : ParamByName('beginDateRange').AsString := formatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy',Date - 30).....i get the error "conversion error from string - 10/25/2012"

reserching this error has provided me no new avenues, do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of the `start_Time` field? (VAR)CHAR or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: both begin and end date fields are datetime

Comment: @Jake - Firebird does not have a datetime data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Interbase 6.0 manual, Embedded SQL guide, chapter 7, Firebird supports conversion from YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.qqq. I also believe it supports American style shorthand dates (eg 1-JAN-2012) for conversion.

It may be there are some locale dependent conversion supported, but in general: use an actual date/timestamp type instead of a string.

**UPDATE**
I initially did not spot the `TRUNC` in your query: it is the cause of the conversion error as this function only works on numbers, see the [manual entry for TRUNC](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-trunc).

Given your comment (and the respons of *ain*) I assume you are only interested in the date part, and want to ignore the time. If so, rewrite your use of `TRUNC` to:

```
CAST(<your-timestamp-field> AS DATE)
```

And the condition `(Trunc(p.start_time) >= :beginDateRange) AND (Trunc(p.start_time) <= :endDateRange)` to:

```
CAST(p.start_time AS DATE) BETWEEN :beginDateRange AND :endDateRange
```

Comment: I do use DateTime fields, not strings. i added the second example in my post to show that if I change my params to AsString, i get the same error

Comment: I guess then the problem is your use of `TRUNC` in the query, as that only converts numbers, not dates. I guess the error might actually about the conversion in `TRUNC`, instead of the parameter. See http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-trunc.html

Comment: It does seem to be the trunc causing the problem, so how do i get rid of the trunc function and select those records that have a true start_date >=:beginDateRange and <=:endDateRange.  I am concerned with the time portion of the date. Will I truly get the coorect result if  ParamByName('beginDateRange').AsDate:= Date - 30;
and ParamByName('endDateRange').AsDate:= Date; ---thanx

Comment: Use `CAST(field AS DATE)` instead of `TRUNC` to get the date part of timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Firebird doesn't support conversion from string to date and time value if string is in 12 hour format. Use 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss' or 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss' formats.

Comment: As I examplained to two others above, i do not use strings. Both my start and end fields are DateTime fields. My params are receiving the values asDateTimes (i even tried asDate). I only shoed the example asString to say that i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

String to date/time conversions usually use user's locale. 
So if you feed a date/time conversion function with string that does not match your date part of the locale - you will get similar errors.

Also specifying date/time values like "10/25/2012" is Locale dependent. So if you execute your program on a computer with different than US Locale (like Mine) - it's likely to fail if using "10/25/2012".

To be Locale independent I suggest two options:

- Use [StrToDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.StrToDateTime), specifying TFormatSettings
- Use ISO 8601 for specifying date/time strings (but I don't think Delphi supports that...)

BTW programs like MS Sql, Excel etc. accept dates in ISO 8601. But you have to check this for FB.

Regarding this:

> ...since my datetime fields are in the "10/25/2012 9:20:49 AM" format in the database...

The internal storage of date/time fields varies between different DB Engines. What you see in your DB Management Software ("10/25/2012 9:20:49 AM" in your case) is the string representation of the data field, usually formatted (again) according your user Locale

Comment: The point of using `AsDate` is to let the DB driver handle the necessary conversion using its own native formats as needed so you don't have to.  If `AsDate` is doing a bad string conversion then it is either a `TParam` bug or a DB driver bug.

Comment: I do not use strings, I use DateTime fields, not strings. i added the second example in my post to show that if I change my params to AsString, i get the same error.

Comment: @JakeSnake: So may be Remy Lebeau is right - may be it is DB driver bug? What components do you use for accessing the database?

Comment: @JakeSnake: Also does that problem occurs for all the three DB Engines you use or one of them?

Answer (score 0):

if you connected with DB from Firebird 1.0  under the server Firebird 2.1 (for example) you need  todo backup and restore under Firebird 2.1